# Django REST Framework/Django - extra user model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my project I've two different types of users:

1. regular Django user
2. worker - user which sends messages through application API and authenticates with token (basic Django rest framework token authentication)

The problem is that Token object is connected with django User object. What would be the best solution - create new user model for my worker? I don't want to extend User model because I want to have "Users" and "Workers" in my admin panel.

```
class Worker(models.Model):
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()

    #  but it's not the way I wish it was done:
    #  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

In general how would you solve the problem when part of users login normally with login/password and some of the users (workers) use token as an authenticating credentials ?

Comment: Could you post your models? Is `worker` somehow connected to the regular user model?

Comment: In fact, worker model contains only fields: ip (GenericIPAddress), created_date and last_updated_date. I tried to inherit from  AbstractBaseModel but it contains a lot of unnecessary information like password etc.

Comment: I also tried to add foreign key to User in my Worker model, but then in admin panel User object must be created before creating Worker object. And Token object (from Django REST Framework) must also be created before creating worker :/

Comment: What about inheriting from abstract base user? Or are you wanting to have this point to existing users?

Comment: Nope, I don't want to point to exisitng users. The problem is Token model from REST framework points to normal users. And if I add FK to User model in my Worker model it doesn't change anything because I still have to create normal User first, then Token and finally Worker. What I want is to have a separated Worker model and only worker objects can authenticate with token.

Comment: Ahhh, while it is generally discouraged you could do what I have below by inheriting the AUTH_USER_MODEL although you'd be better off creating your own User model by inheriting AbstractBaseUser and defining those fields directly within it. If you inherit AbstractBaseUser you also get the added benefit of removing typically unnecessary fields that come packaged within the default user model.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are wanting to have those same fields but want the table space to be unique you could do:

```
class Worker(models.AbstractBaseUser):
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()
```

Otherwise, if you want the worker to inherit you could do what is essentially a join by straight inheriting your auth user class by doing:

```
class Worker(AUTH_USER_MODEL):
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
    last_update = models.DateTimeField()
```

Comment: Mmm... how about populating fields like password? It's in AbstractBaseUser class... I mean - I get this error: "You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'password' to bankworker without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows)."

Comment: You could just define a default password like an api key if a user is never going to use it or be able to access it.

Comment: Do I have to create manager for my custom user to set password to some dummy value?

Comment: Well, when I want to create new Token I still need a normal Django User object. Is there any opportunity to force TokenAuthentication point to  another user model?